# HOw to make reordering false for specific columns in Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

How to make reordering false for specific columns in Telerik MVC Grid
What needs to be added here? I could not find anything useful from the documentation

```
 .Reorderable(reordering => reordering.Columns(false))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly its not possible but we can achieve this,

First make grid Reorderable property like this **.Reorderable(reordering => reordering.Columns(true))** then grid event for columnreorder.

In columnreorder function restrict specific column

Answer (score 1):

The Grid does not allow such configuration. The re-size-ing or reordering feature could be either activated for all the columns or disabled.
Found this [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/prevent-specific-column-from-re-ordering)